Executing multiple calibration circuits on IBM real backend
I am testing a new algorithm for quantum error mitigation based on fuzzy clustering. As you can see in the piece of code below the calibration step is composed of multiple instances, that is I want to run each calibration circuit multiple times, let's say 10, for some post processing we are not interested in now. When running the code on local simulator it works fine but when I try to run it on IBM real backend the program is not retrieving any result, resulting in a timeout error, although on IBM quantum platform the job is successfully executed. Furthermore, when I manually retrieve results from IBM quantum platform, it looks like one single instance has been executed.
qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits) # Quantum register initialization
exp = CorrelatedReadoutError(qr, backend=backend)
meas_calibs, state_labels = exp.circuits()
if draw == True:
    for c in meas_calibs: # Return a list of measurement calibration circuits for the full Hilbert space
        print(c)

dict={}
for s in state_labels:
    dict[s]=list()
for n in range(num_runs):
    l_gen = tqdm(range(number_of_instances), desc="Number of instances") 
    for i in l_gen:
    
        transpiled_circuit = transpile(meas_calibs, backend, optimization_level=0)
        cal_results = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=shots).result()
        
        for j in range(len(state_labels)):
            count=cal_results.get_counts(j)
            count_l=qu.convertInList(count, num_qubits)
            dict[state_labels[j]].append(count_l)
    for s in state_labels:
        matrix=np.array(dict[s]).T
        utils.save_obj(matrix, path+"Alldata_"+str(number_of_instances)+"_"+s+"_"+str(n))
print('Data created!')

Maybe it is necessary to create a batch or a session in order to execute a program with this type of structure, I could not figure out reading Qiskit documentation.
